# What does 'too few arguments to function 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' mean?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am coding with c++, really simple stuff.

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char cName[30], cFirst[15], cSur[30];


    cout << "Enter your name: " << endl;
    cin.getline(cName, 29);


    for( int i = 0; i < 29; i++)
      if(cName[i] == ' ')
       break;

    strncpy(cFirst, cName, i);


    cFirst[i] = '\0';
    strncpy(cSur,cName + i + 1);
    cSur[i] = '\0';
    cout << cSur << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the program stops compiling at `strncpy(cFirst, cName, i);` and I get this error message 'too few arguments to function 'char* strncpy(char*, const char*, size_t)' . Could someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sure the error isn't in this line `strncpy(cSur,cName + i + 1);`?

Comment: Just how unclear is that error message?

Comment: In addition to the compiler error (caused by not passing enough args to strncpy), this program has Undefined Behavior (i.e., will probably segfault) if someone's first name is longer than 15 chars -- cName only holds 15 chars, but on the line `strncpy(cFirst,cName,i)`, `i` can be greater than 15.

Comment: @EdwardLoper: I don't know about "probably segfault", there's a reasonable chance that `cFirst` is between `cName` and `cSur` on the stack, and that in case of buffer overrun, the UB will manifest as writing into one of them. Of course you're right that it's wrong, whether it crashes or not. It's also UB if someone's first name is exactly 15 characters, at `cFirst[i] = '\0';` when `i == 15`.

Comment: The lesson to learn here is to pay more attention to the compiler diagnostics and read them carefully. The compiler will have told you which line the problem  was on but you ignored it and looked at the wrong line.

Answer (score 9):

`strncpy()` takes three arguments, only two are supplied in the second call:

```
strncpy(cSur,cName + i + 1);
```

As this is C++, consider using `std::string` instead of `char[]` (or `char*`). There is a version of [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) that takes a `std::string` as an argument and populates it, removing the need for a fixed length array. You can then use the [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to split the line into first name and last name:

```
std::string full_name("john prog rammer");

const size_t first_space_idx =  full_name.find(' ');
if (std::string::npos != first_space_idx)
{
    const std::string first_name(full_name.substr(0, first_space_idx));
    const std::string surname(full_name.substr(first_space_idx + 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however this is an exercise in increasing my familiarity with the c++ language and so I choose to use a char array. In future in order to write better code I'll use the string type.

Comment: `std::string` is part of the language.

Answer (score 4):

It means, pretty clearly if you ask me, that you provide only 2 arguments instead of 3:

```
strncpy(cSur,cName + i + 1);
```

Comment: yes, thanks all for their responses. I changed strncpy(cSur,cName + i + 1); to strcpy(cSur,cName + i + 1); and the program was able to compile. May some please explain the difference?

Comment: @LegItJoe: `strncpy()` takes 3 arguments, `strcpy()` takes 2 arguments. The additional parameter in the former is the number of characters you intend to copy.When a function is called there is a *type checking*, the number of arguments in the function call must match the number of arguments in the function declaration.

Comment: @LegItJoe what he said. You can find this stuff out from google though.

Answer (score 2):

It's complaining that it takes in 3 arguments but you're not supplying 3.

would it be this line:

```
strncpy(cSur,cName + i + 1);
```

Here you're only supplying 2 as you're adding i and 1 to cName